# Bit Shifting Error on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am developing C++ libraries for the Arduino 2560 Mega and I have come across an interesting bug.

```
uint8_t resolution = 15;

uint32_t numDiscreteLevels = (1 << resolution);   //yields a value of 0xFFFF8000

uint32_t numDiscreteLevels = ((uint32_t)1 << resolution);   //yields 0x8000 (correct value)
```

It seems that in the first line, signed bits are padded onto the value before being assigned to the variable. According to promotion rules I believe that the 1 should be cast to an unsigned integer. But even then, I thought signed padding only occurs when you shift left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the AVR architecture, an `int` is 16 bits -- not 32! This means that all numbers, including integer constants, are treated as a `int16_t` unless otherwise specified.

This means that `1 << 8` is `(int16_t) 0x8000`, not `(int32_t) 0x00008000` as it would be on a 32-bit platform. Since this is a signed value and it has its high bit set, it's negative (specifically, -32768), and sign-extending it to a `uint32_t` gives `0xffff8000`.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the mask value as an unsigned directly to see how that affects the behavior, which should be as expected.:

```
uint8_t resolution = 15;
uint32_t numDiscreteLevels = 1u << resolution;
```

`1u << 15` is `0x8000u` whereas `1 << 15` as a 16-bit value is -32767.

Comment: Sorry! i made an edit. the resolution i was using is actually 15

Comment: @JohnDoe:  I updated it.  1 << 15 signed converted to 32 bits would provide unexpected results if you expected 1 to be unsigned.